# Is there a way to Manually Control Fan Speed for my HP Pavilion Gaming 15 ec2xxx?

Tags: laptop, fan, speed, noise, amd-ryzen

I've a HP Pavilion Gaming 15 ec2xxx with an AMD Ryzen 5600H and a GTX 1650 GDDR6.
I'd like to manually control my fan speed but I can't find anything working.
I tried with Notebookfancontroller but can't find a working config, I tried downloading OMEN Gaming HUB but it doesn't let me control the fan speed.
Are there other software I can use/try or does someone have a config for Notebookfancontroller that work with my laptop? With the config I've tried it basically go back and forward to "Disabled" and "Read-Only"

Thank you to everyone!

Comment: Have you tried SpeedFan?

Comment: Yes, I've tried SpeedFan, but can't control

Answer (score 0):

Use the HP Compaq 15-s103tx config in Notebook Fan Control version 1.6.3. After installing/updating to 1.6.3,

- click the three dots beside the HP Compaq 15 config.
- Next, click "Edit".
- After that, go to "Fan Configuration",
- click "CPU Fan" or what pops up for you.
- Click "Edit" and set "Min. fan speed:" to "53" and set "Max. fan speed:" to "100".
- Finally, click "Ok" then click "Save" in the top left.
- Exit the config editor and click "Apply" then click "Enable".

It should start out slow but within 20 to 30 seconds, it will reach desired fan speeds and stay. I personally did this because mine would always overheat and shutdown. So, I set my fan speed to 100% and then did the process I typed earlier and it stopped the fans from slowing back down. If you do not want your fans to be loud, ignore this answer but it will keep your laptop cool.

Links: https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/releases